Minting stablecoin Aiken example
I'm having trouble building the off-chain code to mint stable-coins from lecture 9, with Aiken. I deployed the oracle NFT with datum rate as a reference script:
const tx = await lucid 
    .newTx()
    .mintAssets({ [token]: 1n }, Data.void())     // no redeemer 
    .collectFrom([aliceUTxO])
    .attachMintingPolicy(nftPolicy)
    .payToAddressWithData(oracleAddr, { inline: Data.to(1n), scriptRef: oracleValidator }, { [token]: 1n })
    .complete()

I query the oracle NFT UTxO with rate = 1, but in my mint:
    .newTx()
    .readFrom([oracleScriptUTxO])
    .payToContract(collateralAddr, { inline: collateral_datum }, { lovelace: 20_000_000n })     
    .mintAssets({ [USDA]: 10_000_000n }, Data.to(minting_redeemer))   
    .attachMintingPolicy(stablecoinPolicy)
    .addSignerKey(bobPKH)
    .complete()

returns
error: Uncaught (in promise) "Redeemer (Mint, 0): The provided Plutus code called 'error'.\n\nExBudget {\n    mem: 148621,\n    cpu: 58366996,\n}\n\n"

The minting branch of the Aiken validator is taken from the lecture:
...
when redeemer is {
      Minting -> {
        let oracle_rate: Int =
          get_oracle_rate(reference_inputs, params.mp_oracle_validator)
        expect [collateral_output]: List<Output> =
          find_script_outputs(outputs, params.mp_collateral_validator)
        let collateral_output_datum: CollateralDatum =
          get_collateral_datum(collateral_output)
     
        let collateral_output_amount: Int = lovelace_of(collateral_output.value)

        let stablecoin_minted_amount: Int =
          get_total_minted_stablecoin(ctx, policy_id)

        let check_mint_positive = stablecoin_minted_amount > 0

        let check_max_mint =
          max_mint(
            collateral_output_amount,
            oracle_rate,
            params.mp_collateral_minPercent,
          ) >= stablecoin_minted_amount
        // Collateral datum must match params
        let check_collateral_output_datum =
          check_collateral_output_datum(
            collateral_output_datum,
            stablecoin_minted_amount,
            extra_signatories,
            policy_id,
          )

        // Final checks
        and {
          check_mint_positive?,
          check_max_mint?,
          check_collateral_output_datum?,
        }
      }

...

